# Gamemaker game freezing computer

Tags: freeze, game-maker

My friend is currently making a game in gamemaker, but whenever I test it out for him my computer seems to just completely lock up. My PC that I am testing on is no way underpowered, it has a 2500k, Radeon 6950 and 8GB RAM. My RAM, GPU and CPU usage is barely touched during the freeze. If I am playing music at the time of the freeze the speakers just buzz. Whenever is occurs a full system reboot is always required, nothing at all responds. The image of the game stays on the screen, mouse, keyboard and restart button don't respond. This question may be better suited for the Gamemaker forums, but it could be an issue with my computer. I am unsure. I can play MW2 and Crysis for hours without it crashing, so it is either a software problem or something weird. All of my temps are normal. Others have suggested checking while loops, but wouldn't an infinite loop cause the CPU usage to rise?

Comment: A complete freeze like this often indicates a problem with the graphic card driver.

Comment: I've uninstalled my drivers and then reinstalled CCC 12.2

Answer (score 1):

In any of your loops that have a potential of running infinitely, put io_handle(); (I think thats the command) This command somehow keeps windows from thinking a program has frozen. If that isn't the case... then try to play the music through an extension like fMod or another one. Furthermore, try it on another computer is it just your computer? Your computer doesn't sound underpowered at all... but what about your operating system? If you're using xp it may not support the Directx that GM requires. I believe that its very easy to make gm games very directx intensive, so check that out. Good luck! I love Game Maker!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an infinite loop in your code. Try stripping away your code, compile, and test if your computer freezes again. Then build back up to where you started from.

Comment: Odd thing is, it doesn't crash on my friends computer.

Comment: That could be because your friends' computer has multiple cores and your computer does not.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue is probably due to something internally in game maker, OR it could be an issue with a listener or script you may have bound to a sprite or object. Begin removing things, one by one, until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to strip out pieces of code part by part and isolate the function / code that is causing the freeze. Then come back here and tell us the status.

Answer (score 0):

I've kind of seen this before on another Gamemaker game. Do you have any infinite loops or shaders in your game? The last game that had this problem was caused by a bad shader.